# Do morph targets work with three.js canvasrenderer?

Tags: three.js

Simple question.  Do morph targets work with three.js canvasrenderer? And if not is there a way I can fake it?  Like I have a plane with an image on it.  I have a bunch of vertices that I want to move around that will morph the image.  Is this even possible with canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have that implemented yet. Also need to try implementing BufferGeometry into CanvasRenderer too.

Comment: Morph targets are now supported in CanvasRenderer with Geometry, and [#14747](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14747) would add them for BufferGeometry.